# How add ipAddres o clientAddress the token in Keycloak

Tags: angular, jwt, token, keycloak

I have keycloak version 12 and I have not been able to add the client's ip to the token, perform the procedure of adding the clientAddress to the mapper with user session note, I get the users from an ldap ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Client IP is not available in the user session note, unless the user is a Service Account (private client) - [Relevant Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/12.0/server_admin/index.html#_protocol-mappers_oidc-user-session-note-mappers).

Easiest way to achieve this is to write a plugin for keycloak, adding an event listener on user login/token refresh to add to the user session notes.
Created this quick example - https://github.com/CharlyRipp/keycloak-user-details-provider.

Comment: Charly, I use your plugin, it works fine for ip address, there is any form to get the client hostname?

Comment: Hey @PabloAleman, I'm not sure on that - I haven't tried but you may be able to get access to the HttpRequest and grab the 'origin' header somehow. If possible, I'd suggest utilizing the realm/client if possible instead. For keycloak's hostname you can utilize [org.keycloak.common.util.HostUtils](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/bfce612641a70e106b20b136431f0e4046b5c37f/common/src/main/java/org/keycloak/common/util/HostUtils.java) to get it ( `HostUtils.getHostname()` ).